# Remove loaded drake cache objects from RAM

Tags: r, drake-r-package

I've run a plan to create a large set of objects in drake's cache. Now, outside of a plan, I ran `lapply` over a subset of those objects so I can summarize some of their properties and plan my next steps.

I'm using `readd` to load each one of these cached objects inside of the function I'm applying over, but they seem to still use up RAM after I'm done with them. That's a problem in my scenario because it's 100 GiB of RAM by the time it's finished. I'm not sure where in the environment I should be looking for them if I need to explicitly remove them.

I understand that drake is doing something similar to memoization with the cache, since if I `readd` the same object twice, the first one takes time to read from disk, and the second time is instantaneous. But in this scenario, I'd like to treat the cache as a simple data source like any other file, so that an object doesn't take up RAM if it's `rm()`'d or goes outside of the scope.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! It looks like the `storr` object returned by `get_cache` or `new_cache` has a `flush_cache` method. Calling that, then `gc()`, returns the memory.

Should `flush_cache` be documented somewhere in drake, even though it comes from storr?

I also found that if I call `readd` from multiple processes with `mclapply`, the objects don't stay in RAM, since they don't get transferred back to the main process.

Comment: Might be worth asking on the [drake github page](https://github.com/ropensci/drake) if you think the docs need updating, or have a suggestion for improvements.

Comment: Glad you figured this out before I got to it. The main issue in `drake` should now be fixed in https://github.com/ropensci/drake/commit/6a05b979283f79a2ea8444020c5450ad2b9611d0 and https://github.com/ropensci/drake/commit/bf88250f7ea63b545a421f08433ec64c74ec79e8. I just set `use_cache` to `FALSE` in the`storr` function calls that save and load targets. `drake` has its own memory management strategy (see the `memory_management` and `garbage_collection` arguments of `make()`) so we do not need `storr`'s in-memory cache anyway. So we probably don't need more docs at this point.

Comment: Major update: the manual has a new chapter on memory management: https://ropenscilabs.github.io/drake-manual/memory.html. Some of the features are only available in the newly-released `drake` version 7.4.0.